# Is it possible to use the access token from firebase to authorize YouTube API?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, youtube-api, fetch-api

I am trying to post comment on the YouTube video using the YouTube API using ReactJS. But instead of using the `gapi` for signInWithGoogle, I am using firebase and the access_token returned by firebase.

My code looks something like this.

```
const url = `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=${MY_API_KEY}&part=snippet`

const requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json'
  }
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "snippet": {
      "videoId": "[SOME_VIDEO_ID]",
      "topLevelComment": {
        "snippet": {
          "textDisplay": "test",
        }
      }
    }
  })
}

fetch(url, requestOptions)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

But it throws error saying that

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Invalid Credentials",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "authError",
                "location": "Authorization",
                "locationType": "header"
            }
        ],
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `firebase` I used a `npm` package called `react-google-login`, which provides the access_token. I used that access token to authorize the YouTube API, which worked.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login